# How to have Luxon's Intl API working in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, intl, luxon

I've been using Luxon for quite sometime as a replacement for moment, being light weight and an overall great documentation, I've now bumped into a case where I needed to use luxon's toFormat function to write the date month name.

Now this problem only occurs in Android and not in iOS, I'm assuming because some of the javascript in iOS also comes from Safari, and the browser does support Luxon's Intl API.

Basically my question is how do you make Luxon's Intl Api work on Android?

React-Native version: 0.62.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So while I was writting my question I was still reading luxon's documentation and searching for any possible solution.

From Luxon's docs I was redirected to [JSC Android Buildscripts](https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts)

Which at first sight looked like a promising solution, while at the same time I had found an issue that was reported in react-native's github [Fresh Install Android Broken on React Native 0.60 RC2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25415)

And basically by reading both sides I found that in the app/build.gradle file there's a variable called jscFlavor, which literally states

> For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
>
> `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`

Basically by changing the jscFlavor to 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+' I was able to have Intl working in Android with Luxon

Comment: But that means you can't use RN Hermes correct?

Comment: Looks like `Intl` ships with Hermes by default starting RN 0.65: https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/23#issuecomment-816126715

Comment: Which Expo SDK 44 doesn't support, so we have to wait for SDK 45 and see what version it supports.